# Bitwise operation between int and long

Tags: java, c#, interop, bitwise-operators

I've searched for documentation about this, but I don't seem to find anything. If I have an `int` and a `long`, how are the bitwise operations defined? Is the `int` just padded before the operation?

Ex:

```
int a;
long b;

// Do something with a and b

return a | b;
```

I'm interested in both Java and C#.

Comment: In c#, before applying the operator, `int` will be implicitly converted to `long`. So, you're indeed working with two long numbers.

Comment: The C# language specification is included with every VS install: have you tried reading it? (Any C# answer ultimately will be whatever is in the spec.)

Comment: For Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1

Comment: `Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.` See [§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) and [§15.22.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.1).

Comment: In Java the `int` will first be converted to a `long`. It will be padded with `1` if it was negative and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. Yes, the docs you linked shows they convert to `long` before the operation.

Answer (score 3):

For C#, the C# V5 specification (as included with VS 2013) says:

1. In §7.11.1defines the available operators:

> ```
> int operator |(int x, int y);
> uint operator |(uint x, uint y);
> long operator |(long x, long y);
> ulong operator |(ulong x, ulong y);
> ```

so there are no mixed type versions of binary-or.

2. In §6.12 "6.1.2 Implicit numeric conversions", the following implicit (ie. automatically applied by the complier) conversions are defined:

> - From `int` to `long`, `float`, `double`, or `decimal`.
> - […]
> - From `long` to `float`, `double`, or `decimal`.

So, `int` to `long` is available but not visa-versa.

Ie. the compiler will convert `a` to a `long`, and then binary-or the two longs to give a `long` result.

As noted in the comments to the question, for Java the same applies.